# How to change ip of azure gateway

Tags: ip, azure, gateway

How to change frontend ip of Azure Application Gateway?

The ip I want to change to exist as a Public Ip resource in azure.

In the "Frontend IP configurations" I can see the old IP beeing used. But its not possible to change it or remove the configuration. Its also not possible to create a new Frontend IP configuration.

Do we need to do this from powershell and how?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not trying to add multiple IPs to the gateway. Because the Application Gateway supports only 1 public IP address.

Yes, you would need to use PS to set the values and you can use the ***Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayFrontendIPConfig*** cmdlet to update a front-end IP configuration.

Here's a reference to the MS documentation on the PS module:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/set-azurermapplicationgatewayfrontendipconfig?view=azurermps-6.2.0

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Source: my tests and https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/4133